# Limit one to many relationship to a custom maximum number in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
A hasMany(B)
B belongsTo(A)
```

I want to limit the number of B to a maximum of 5.

1 row in A can have maximum of 5 rows in B

Is there any way? Or should I use `1-1` relationship with max 5 columns

Comment: You'd have to put some validation on the set or add function, that validates that the collection in question has 4 or less before adding a new element, otherwise throwing an error. I don't know specifically if Laravel has a validator that can do this, in Symfony I would write a custom validaor.

Comment: `if(count($A->B) < 5)`  before `save()` else error ! Got it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do.

1. Count number of rows of B against given A at it creation request.
2. Show error if its more than 5.

There is no direct way to limit the B using Laravel, as far as I know.

Comment: I too got that just secs late . Anyways are you sure there aren't any other ways ?

Comment: Yes as far as my knowledge. But lets wait for some other answer.

Comment: I think you can limit the record in the relationship let's say you have defined a related function getrecords() in model A then you may do getrecords(){return $this-hasMany("App\Model")->take(5);}

Comment: @KhanShahrukh while setting not getting rows. `take(5)` is used while getting rows.

Comment: I read it wrong may be that's why I commented and did not answer

Comment: Agree with this answer - handle it in validation.